# How do I get started using Amazon Web Service on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, web-services, windows-phone-7

Can anyone help or direct me to a guide for using Amazon Web Service in Visual Studio 2010? I tried downloading the .Net SDK from the amazon website but it wouldn't let me add the reference to the .dll because it said that it wasn't build for Windows Phone 7.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no library for WP7 yet. This is because AWS does not allow cross domain requests (although there are some workarounds [like this one](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/05/access-amazon-s3-services-with-silverlight-2.aspx)), and therefore there's not much from the Silverlight world. 
Your options here are:

- Create a proxy service that talks with AWS through the .NET api. You will need to publish this service when you go live with your app though.
- Build your own library based on REST (AWS will stop supporting SOAP next month). You can find the complete documentation of each web service [here](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/). Note that this would take much more time and effort, but you could make it open source so other developers can benefit and contribute to it too.

Comment: Thanks. Although that really sucks. That seems complicated. Is there another web service that you would recommend using instead?

Comment: Depends on what kind of service you need. Do you need an online database, a storage service or something else? You could use Windows Azure, but the recommended architecture involves creating a service layer, so it's basically the same problem. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521148(v=vs.92).aspx